# Event when space is pressing, only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I have some issues: I have this : (in a function..)

```js
var space = 0;

setInterval(space, 20);
var keys = {}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});

function space() {
    for (var direction in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
        if (direction == 32) {
                space++;
                console.log(space);
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

32 == Space key, but I saw in the console that space is pressed 3 times (space == 3), keyup keypress and keydown (I think), how can I have just "space = 1" when space is pressed ?

Comment: When I put setInterval to 200 it work better, I guess I found my error !

Comment: First, you haven't posted complete code. Second, how about explaining exactly what it is you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that since it's running every 20 ms, as you hold down the space bar the space function is continuously incrementing the count. I added a flag to prevent another execution until the key is released and it works fine. Really you should just use the keypress event and check there if the keyCode === 32 to track your count. Fewer events will be fired. If you want to see what was happening you can comment out the flag and check the console.

```js
var spaceCount = 0;
var running = false;
var keys = {}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  console.log("keycode", e.keyCode);
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  console.log("keyup")
  delete keys[e.keyCode];
  running = false;
});

function space() {
  if(running) return;
  for (var direction in keys) {
    running = true;
    console.log(direction);
    if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
    if (direction == 32) {
      spaceCount++;
      console.log("count: " + spaceCount);
      console.log(keys);
    }
  }
}

setInterval(space, 20);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will be helpful:

```
var space = 0; 
    var keys = {};
    var keys2 = {};

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

setInterval(function(){spacing()}, 20); 

function spacing() {

    if (keys[32] && !keys2[32])
        {
            space++;
            keys2[32] = true;
        }
        else if(!keys[32])
        {
            keys2[32] = false;
        }

console.log(space);
 }
```